# VS 2010 Build error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am compiling a executable Win32 console application in 2010 which was developed in VS 2005. I have checked all the settings with VS 2005, still it throws following Build Error. Please help.

```
       1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: vssreg, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
    1>  stdafx.cpp
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(543): error C2065: '_In_opt_z_' : undeclared identifier
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(543): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'const'
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(543): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(543): error C2182: '_invalid_parameter' : illegal use of type 'void'
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(543): error C2491: '_invalid_parameter' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(543): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(550): error C2065: '_In_opt_z_' : undeclared identifier
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(550): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'const'
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(550): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
    1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(550): error C2182: '_invoke_watson' : illegal use of type 'void'

When I tried to put /ShowIncludes option , im getting following includes info

    1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: vssreg, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  Note: including file: c:\rajesh\hak\hak27x64\2010\hak_27_x64\itxvssreg\stdafx.h
1>  Note: including file:  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\iostream
1>  Note: including file:   c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\istream
1>  Note: including file:    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ostream
1>  Note: including file:     c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ios
1>  Note: including file:      c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocnum
1>  Note: including file:       c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\climits
1>  Note: including file:        c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\yvals.h
1>  Note: including file:         c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>  Note: including file:          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Include\sal.h
1>  Note: including file:          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vadefs.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line from your show includes is a bit of a giveaway

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Include\sal.h

Somehow you are still including a VS 2005 header. As a first step I would try renaming the v6.1 directory see if that fixes the problem. If that's it then look to your project settings so that C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs is not referenced.

Comment: OK, well what happened when you tried it? Give us a clue and someone might be able to help further.

Comment: It is stucking as i mentioned in question. '_In_opt_z_' : undeclared identifier and series of errors

Comment: Well `_In_opt_z_` is defined in the file sal.h, do /ShowIncludes again and tell me which directory you are including sal.h from. It was wrong before maybe it's still wrong.

Comment: It has worked. I have directly give include path VC\Include of VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

Also (in addition to checking Includes, on `VC++ Directories` and `C++\General`), try to change `Platform Toolset` in project properties.
[image]

Check registry keys with SDK registration. Yes, example is for Windows v7.1.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows]
"CurrentInstallFolder"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1\\"
"ProductVersion"="v7.1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows]
"CurrentInstallFolder"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1\\"
"CurrentVersion"="v7.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Im building this project in Windows 2003 server. I dont have option for Windows 7.1 SDK

Comment: So, what option you are using? `v100`?

Comment: Yes using  v100 option. Im building this app for 64- bit

Comment: `v100` is limited and strange implementation of WinSDK. Try to install Full v7.1?

Comment: But it is working okay with VS 2005, when i'm porting to VS 2010 only givign this error.

Comment: VS 2005 has different crtdefs.h. You are trying to use `crtdefs.h` from 2010 and `sal.h` from 2005. It fails.

Comment: Thanks . Making the VC Include file instead of SDK file did a trick.